# Assigning values to an array in a separate function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am trying to write a code that will generate 100000 random numbers in double type and assign them to an array. This should be done in a separate function to be called from main and I also cannot use any global variables. The function should be in the format of `double createRandomNumbers()`. The array created however should be available to use from main function also. I have written the code below for my function `double createRandomNumbers()`.

```
` int main(void)
    createRandomNumbers();
    printf("%.2f",randomNumberset[1]);
    return(0); `


`    double createRandomNumbers()
{   
    double randomNumberset[100000] ;int i;
    for(i=0;i<100000;i++)
    {
        randomNumberset[i]=(double)(10000*((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX));
    }
}`
```

Arrays are pointers right? So in theory I should be able to use the array in the main without declaring it once more. Yet I get the error:
`[Error] 'randomNumberset' was not declared in this scope.`

I feel like I should be using a pointer somewhere but cannot really figure out where.

Comment: If an array was a pointer, it wouldn't have a different name.  When passed as an argument to a function, an array decays to a pointer, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: "Arrays are pointers right?" - no, they're arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving under your given conditions is not possible.

If you can't use globals, then to fill the array in the function and use it from main, you must do one of two things: (1) allocate the array in main, and pass it to the function to fill, or (2) allocate the array in the filling function and return it to main. There are no other options, and a function declared `double createRandomNumbers()` does neither.  For option 1, it should be `void createRandomNumbers(double *buf)`; for option 2 it should be `double * createRandomNumbers()`.

Personally, I would do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

double *randomArray(int count) {
    double *dp = malloc(count * sizeof(double));
    if (dp) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
            dp[i] = ((double)rand()) / RAND_MAX;
        }
    }
    return dp;
}

int main(int ac, char *av[]) {
    srand(time(0));

    double *dp = randomArray(100000);
    if (dp) {
        . . .
        free(dp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that a static array would work: I consider that a global in the spirit of the exercise.

Comment: ok so if I change it to ` double * createRandomNumbers() ` how do I proceed? I did not know that a function could be assigned to a pointer.

Comment: The function is returning a pointer...in that case, it should return a pointer to the first element of the array that you create in the function. I've added some sample code.

Comment: `sizeof double` should be either `sizeof *dp` or `sizeof(double)`

Comment: @AhmetUmutDurmuş it's not "a function could be assigned to a pointer" case that the author talks about what he means by the above statement is that  the function returns a pointer to a double datatype in this case an array of doubles. Once you collect these in the main function you could start reading values as *(doub_arr),*(doub_arr+1) etc as the 0th,1st .. etc elements of an array

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Thanks a lot. I have been trying for hours to get it done in ` double createRandomNumbers() ` not knowing it cannot be done. You saved me of hours of struggle.